# read cookies httpurlconnection android

Tags: android, cookies, httpurlconnection

I want to read all cookies from the server but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection already established
```

How can I read the cookies before connecting? I tried putting the cookie read code before defining the connection but It does not work until I define the connection which establishes the connection which prevents me from reading cookies...
Any help please?

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.read;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

List<String> cookies = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(l);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

View.OnClickListener l = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        if(!edt.getText().toString().equals("")){
            readData(edt.getText().toString());
        }
    }
};

void readData(String text){
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;

    try{
        url = new URL("http://"+text);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
         if(cookies==null){
               conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
            }
            if(cookies!=null){
                for(String cookie : cookies){
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
                }
            }
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        String post = "mobile_app="+URLEncoder.encode("1","UTF-8");
        out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(post);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String line = "";
        String data = "";
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            data+=line;
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(data);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds a bit strange. As a client you set the cookies before establishing the connection - if you know them. The Set-Cookie header, the server returns, can only be read as soon as the answer of the server has been returned. Then of course it's to late to set any client-cookies :-)

In other words: You simply cannot read cookies from the server before you send the request.

The server sends "`Set-Cookie`" headers, and *afterwards* clients send these cookies with every *following* request. So you can set your "`Cookie`" headers only from the second request onwards.